# How can i get raw Inputstream response from JAX-WS client?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, sax

I've got an a client for JAX-WS webservice. The problem that i faced is the exception `Unmarshalling Error: Maximum Number of Child Elements limit (50000) Exceeded` when response is mapping to Java Objects. So i think about manually SAX parsing response. Is there any kind of hack/interceptor that allows me to use nice JAX-WS method binding with manually SAX parsing(through `InputStream`) the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there's no need to do that, since you can just override the property

```
 org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements
```

to get rid of the exception. For more information, check it out the official documentation: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/security.html

Comment: Ok, overriding this property will remove Unmarshalling Error, but after that large xml answer with jaxb provider will generate a lot of object and i will receive heap problem. So question is actual again. How can i using cxf jaxws receive stream answer and parse it with sax? Or is there another way to solve problem ?